# UITableViewCell getting reused

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` called symptomtable ...and there is remedytable when `UISwitch` is ON in remedytable I am display an `UIImage` on symptomtableviewcell to highlight that `UISwitch` is ON for that cell . When i switch ON in remedytable of first symptom I am displaying `UISwitch` but the cell is getting reused and the image is showing in other symptomtableview cell as well. Can anyone help me out with this?

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    if (tableView==symptomsTableView)
    {
        PPsymptomTableCell *cell;

        static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cellIdentifier";
        cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

        if (cell==nil)
        {
            cell=[[PPsymptomTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
        int symptomIDSelected;

        symptomIDSelected = [[[mainsymptArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"SymptID"]intValue];

        NSLog(@"%d",[[activeNotificationDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:symptomIDSelected]]intValue]);

        for (int i = 0; i<activeNotificationDictionary.count; i++)
        {
            if([[activeNotificationDictionary objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:symptomIDSelected]]intValue] == symptomIDSelected)
            {
                cell.selectedCellImageDisplay.hidden=NO;
            }
            else
            {
                cell.selectedCellImageDisplay.hidden=YES;
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"end of symptoms cell for row");
        if (searching==YES)
        {
            cell.symptomCellLabel.text=[[searchSymptomsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SymptName"];
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            NSArray *sectionArray=[mainIndexDictionary objectForKey:[allKeysArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
            cell.symptomCellLabel.text=[[sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"SymptIndexName"];
            return cell;
        }
    }
```

Here activenotification dictionary is an `NSMutableDictionary` where it contains the value of remedyID for that particular symptomID.
This is a custom `UITableViewCell` for symptomtable

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.symptomCellImageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

        selectedCellImageDisplay = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedSymptomImage.png"]];
        selectedCellImageDisplay.frame = CGRectMake(230.0, 8.0, 30.0, 30.0);
        selectedCellImageDisplay.hidden=YES;

        symptomCellLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0,0.0 ,280.0,40.0)];
        symptomCellLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Rockwell" size:17];
        symptomCellLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        symptomCellLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:symptomCellLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:selectedCellImageDisplay];
             // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The cell is being reused because you asked for it to be reused (`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`). Because the cell can be reused, you must explicitly set *all* the features of *every* cell, including the presence or absence of the switch and its state.

Comment: can u help me with the problem

Comment: I've written you an entire book about how to program iOS, including a chapter about how table views work: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html Writing _your_ code for your particular situation is up to _you_.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you putting the `UISwitch` into the cell? You need to be sure to set the state of the switch after each time you dequeue or initialize a cell.

Comment: i am adding UISwitch on another tableview called remedyTableView on customcell

Comment: Are you using two UITableViews for the same part of your application?

Comment: Yes i am there are two UITableviews...when i click on one UITableview it navigates to another UITableview